# has_one and mongoid: undefined method `empty?' for #<User>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid

Getting undefined method `empty?' for # error in my controller when trying to save the currently logged_in user to the model.

Using devise and rails 4.

Model:

```
  class Event

  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :date, type: Date

  embeds_many :invitees, cascade_callbacks: true
  embeds_many :participants, cascade_callbacks: true
  embeds_many :comments, cascade_callbacks: true
  embeds_many :options, cascade_callbacks: true

  has_one :owner, :class_name => "User"

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, autosave: true, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :participants, autosave: true, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, autosave: true, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invitees, autosave: true, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner, autosave: true, allow_destroy: true

  end
```

Controller:
    ...
    def create

```
    @event = Event.create(event_params)

    if user_signed_in?
      @event.create_owner(current_user)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        #TODO: Save users attached to event in user collection
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  ....
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
Here is the stacktrace:

> C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-5b0f031992cb/lib/mongoid/attributes/processing.rb:21:in
>   `process_attributes'
>   C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-5b0f031992cb/lib/mongoid/document.rb:110:in`block in initialize'
>   C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-5b0f031992cb/lib/mongoid/threaded/lifecycle.rb:84:in
>   `_building'
>   C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-5b0f031992cb/lib/mongoid/document.rb:104:in`initialize' devise (3.0.4) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:46:in
>   `initialize'
>   C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-5b0f031992cb/lib/mongoid/factory.rb:23:in`
>   new'
>   C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-5b0f031992cb/lib/mongoid/factory.rb:23:in
>   `build'
>   C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-5b0f031992cb/lib/mongoid/relations/builders.rb:93:in`
>   block in creator' app/controllers/events_controller.rb:31:in `create'
>   actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in`
>   send_action' ...

Comment: Did you find the bug ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling the function "empty?" on a User record when it is not defined. In the simplest case this fails in the rails console:

```
1.9.3-p194 :001 > User.first.empty?
    User Load (9.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
    NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for #<User:0x007fe0375d8c10>
```

You could fix this by stubbing out the function in your User model:

```
def empty?
end
```

But it would be better to figure out where you're making the call and fix it. The error trace should tell which file and line it originates from.

Comment: What versions of Rails, Ruby, and Mongoid are you using? Perhaps there is some incompatibility.